Discrete runs in NetLogo's BehaviorSpace
I have a NetLogo model that exports then later imports data. It runs fine but when I try to do an experiment in BehaviorSpace it immediately falls over, I believe because it is doing multiple runs in parallel and one run is importing data from a different run etc. - that is, it's all getting muddled.
Is there any way to force BehaviorSpace to complete one run before moving on to the next?

You can also modify your code so that each BehaviorSpace run uses its own files, by including the run number in the file name.
Instead of file-open "my-data-file.csv" etc., create a variable that holds the file name and set it:
set file-name (word "data-file-for-run-" behaviorspace-run-number ".csv")
The use file-name to write and read the file.


If you run BehaviorSpace with only a single 'Simultaneous runs in parallel' that may do the trick. However, this will increase the time required to complete your experiment- if your model is not extremely complex / long-to-run that may not matter.
Also note the section regarding parallel runs in the run options help. Another possible cause for your issues may be tied to the way BehaviorSpace deals with parallel runs (for example: "This world is not cleared automatically by BehaviorSpace if a parallel run gets re-used for another repetition, which happens quite frequently."), but without more information it's hard to say.
